# Retrive Data Fron Txt File And Save It in Database

Tags: php, mysql

I have A data in txt file I want to save it in database

mytxtfile

```
xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxx
```

I want to Save each line in database...

I want to make a PHP file which take 1st line from txt file and save it in db. Then again second line and so on....

myphpcode

```
$myFile = "data.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$theData = fgets($fh);

$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Persons (ID)
VALUES (''.$theData.'')");

mysqli_close($con);
```

?>

This Code Is Just Saving 1st line..

Comment: Do you really need a PHP script? Because mysql is also able to do this with just one request

Comment: Please Tell me the way how it can be done..

Comment: [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html) or [mysqlimport](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqlimport.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try something like:

```
while (!feof($fh)) {
   $line = fgets($fh);
   mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Persons (ID)
        VALUES ('".$line."')");
}
```

The loop goes through each line of the file and then inserts it into the database.

It is not the most efficient way, especially if you have a very large number of lines, but it does the trick. If you do have very many lines, than you should try and do everything in a single INSERT.

Comment: I think you missed some things inside this code. First advice you can give him is that he did not test if the file exists. The other one is that this approach has a hit for performance because you need to get connection open while you are parsing the file.

Comment: This code worked ;) in seconds all lines are added in db ! thanks

Comment: @DavidLevel, in my opinion you are overthinking the problem, as well as other people that answered here. He did not ask for anything more other than what I have provided, which was a simple way of putting the contents of the file in the database. By following your train of thought, you could end up writing a small book about how to insert 3 lines in a database.

Comment: I know right about that but you can't leave him with an only solution and this one is inside the PHP documentation, that means he could find him by himself really easily. If someone ask for a solution on this site I guess he tried everything and want a better solution. BUt your one works of course

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer your question first. Your code is fine in it's present condition but the problem is only one line being read. If you want to read the complete file content, you'll have to loop through each line. Change your code to include a while loop, like so:

```
$fh = fopen('file.txt', 'r');

while(!feof($fh)){
    $theData = fgets($fh);
    echo $theData; //save it to DB
}
```

[`feof()`](http://php.net/feof) checks for end-of-file on a file pointer. If EOF (end of file) is reached, it'll exit the loop.

---

**Alternative solution:**

Using [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html):

**Example:**

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE Persons
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
  IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

The advantage of using `LOAD DATA INFILE` is that it's considerably faster than other methods, but the speed may vary depending on other factors.

Answer (score 0):

it's as simple as:

```
$ip     = fopen('data.txt', "r");

$line = trim(fgets($ip));
while(!feof($ip)){
  // do something with line in $line
  //....
  // reading next line
  $line = trim(fgets($ip));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities for this question:

First one just parse file using the SplFileObject http://php.net/manual/fr/class.splfileobject.php

In my mind using Spl object is always a good way of coding in PHP.

The second one consist in using LOAD DATA INFILE functionality of MySQL http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html

This is a good way if you don't need to use data from the file but just storing them.